# If statement to show different submit buttons in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, if-statement

I have a form with two submit buttons, one that publishes a post and one that unpublishes a post if it is already published.

I want to only show the unpublish button if the post is published.

If a post is published `@article.publish` is `1`; if not it's `0`.

I have the following code to try and do this but the `if` statement doesn't seem to be working--the unpublish button shows regardless of what `@article.publish` is and the publish button remains hidden.

```
<% if @article.publish = '1' %>
  <div class="four columns">
    <%= f.submit :value => "UNPUBLISH"%>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="four columns">
    <%= f.submit :value => "PUBLISH"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is there something wrong with this syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clean the whole thing up by not repeating the repeated content.

```
<div class="four columns">
  <%= f.submit :value => "#{"UN" if @article.publish }PUBLISH" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers Max, a lot cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

There should be:

```
if @article.publish == '1'
```

Double `==` is for comparison, single `=` is for assignment.

Comment: Yep, but now it's stuck on the publish button and the unpublish button remains hidden no matter what the public value is.

Comment: @Terryfrancis is the `publish` field boolean? If so, it's being coerced automatically into `true` or `false`, so you just need `if @article.publish`.

Comment: yes it is, and by default it is set to be 0. I tried using `if @article.publish` and it is stuck on the unpublish button again :(

Comment: I fixed it by taking out the quotation marks on the 1, answer is below, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by changing

```
<% if @article.publish == '1' %>
```

To

```
 <% if @article.publish == 1 %>
```

I took the quotation marks off on the 1. simples.

Comment: You should just say `if @article.publish`.  `1` happens to be how your database management system (MySql i'm guessing) stores booleans.  In your rails code you should test the boolean rather than the dbms-specific value.